# Check the proof of an upper bound must be greater than or equal to the a lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

$S$ is an ordered set, and have $T\subseteq X$, ($T\neq\varnothing $ ), prove that if $b$ is an upper bound of $T$ and $a$ is a lower bound of $T$, then $a \leq b$.

My proof: (Prove by contradiction) Let $b$ be an upper bound, then every number greater than or equal to $b$ must also be an upper bound. Assume $a \gt b$, then $a$ is an upper bound, which contradicts with the assumption that a is an lower bound. Therefore, we conclude $a \le b$.

Is my proof right? If not, could somebody help to provide a valid proof. Thanks.

Comment: The proof is not right, sup may not exist. Also, you cannot conclude that $a\ne b$, since $T$ may be a one-element set.

Comment: I just edited my proof, is this right then?

Comment: After the assume $a\gt b$. That's impossible. For $b\lt a$, so $a$ is not a lower bound. But trying to twist things into a proof by contradiction is not a good idea. Write like Stella Biderman did. Since $T$ is non-empty, it has an element $t$. Since $a$ is a lower bound, we have $a\le t$. Since $b$ is an upper bound, $t\le b$. It follows that $a\le b$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof works.

You don't need to appeal to sup though, you can just note that, by definition, $a\leq t\leq b$. Then by transitivity we are done as $a\leq b$

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by transitivity. Does it follow from my proof?

Comment: Yes your proof works. The "transitive property" states that if xRy and yRz then xRz. In this particular case, $a<t$ and $t<b$ implies $a<b$. There's another second of logic needed due to the possibly-equals, but it works.

Comment: Why can't $a=b$ if $T$ has only one element?

Comment: @RossMillikan because I'm tired and didn't give that enough thought